# How to correctly export env variables containing spaces in ZSH

Tags: macos, zsh, macos-catalina

Add an env variable containing spaces to `~/.zshrc`

```
export SKIP="-Dskip1 -Dskip2"
export SKIP_NO_SPACES="-Dskip3"
```

Try to use it

```
set -x  
mvn $SKIP $SKIP_NO_SPACES
```

The command that is being executed is actually

> +-zsh:108> mvn '-Dskip1 -Dskip2' -Dskip3

Only the variable that contains spaces gets quoted.

How to avoid the single quotes being added ?

If not using quoting/escaping at all, there is an error when opening the shell:

> /.zshrc:export:11: not valid in this context: -Dskip2

Comment: Why do you think the problem has anything to do with exporting? Don't you see the same behavior with shell variables rather than environment variables? Do you know the difference?

Comment: Sorry for the snarky comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're (kind of) abusing environment variables here. That space is part of the variable, and when you're performing parameter expansion with `$`, it will simply pass that space to the command. `mvn` gets one argument – your variable contents.

As Kamil Maciorowski correctly observes in a comment, this is specific to Zsh. What you are proposing would work in Bash if you left out the quotes:

```bsh
bash-5.0$ export test="foo bar"
bash-5.0$ ls $test
ls: bar: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
bash-5.0$ ls "$test"
ls: foo bar: No such file or directory
```

One alternative to do what you want would be a [global alias](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_8.html) (also a feature of Zsh, not Bash), which can be substituted anywhere in a line. It keeps its spaces:

```
$ alias -g SKIP="-Dskip1 -Dskip2"
$ alias -g SKIP2="-Dskip3"
$ mvn SKIP SKIP2
```

This will simply "append" the string wherever added.

Comment: I wouldn't use a global alias here; just use an array, as this is the kind of situation they were created to handle. `SKIP=(-Dskip1 -Dskip2); SKIP2=(-Dskip3); mvn "${SKIP[@]}" "${SKIP2[@]}"`.

Comment: @chepner Except if I had to type `"${SKIP[@]}"` all day long I'd go crazy. It's a usability/personal preference thing I guess.

Comment: Actually, with default `zsh` settings, `mvn $skip $skip2` would suffice. Two extra characters, but it makes it much more obvious that *something* is being expanded. (And whatever the array expands to won't be subject to further expansion, unlike the aliases.)

Comment: @chepner In that case that would be a good alternative.

Answer (score 14):

The problem has nothing to do with quoting or escaping, it's all to do with word splitting (or the lack thereof). In most shells, if you use a variable that contains whitespace without putting double-quotes around it, the value will be split into "words" based on that whitespace. So if the variable `SKIP` is set to `-Dskip1 -Dskip2` (note that there are no quotes or escapes in this value), and you use it like `mvn $SKIP`, it becomes equivalent to `mvn "-Dskip1" "-Dskip2"`.

But zsh isn't most shells, and (by default) it does not do word splitting. If the variable is set to `-Dskip1 -Dskip2`, then that's what's getting passed to the command, *as a single argument*. The quotes you see in the `set -x` output aren't really there, they are just added to make it explicit that the entire string is being passed as a single argument.

There are a couple of ways to tell zsh that you want word splitting done. You can use the `=` modifier in the expansion:

```
mvn ${=SKIP}
```

Or you can turn on sh-like splitting for all expansions with a shell option:

```
setopt shwordsplit
mvn $SKIP
```

...however, this can have unpleasant side effects, like unexpected splitting of things you thought were single arguments, and expansion of anything that looks like a filename wildcard into a list of filenames. Shell word splitting tends to cause bugs, which is why it's disabled by default in zsh. The really proper way to store multiple strings in a variable is to use an array instead of a plain variable:

```
SKIP=(-Dskip1 -Dskip2)
mvn "${SKIP[@]}"
```

This will work in zsh, bash, and some other shells (but not those without array support). However, you cannot export arrays from zsh (well, you can run `export SKIP`, but it doesn't do anything). Arrays are a shell feature, while environment variables are an OS thing that only supports plain strings. Do you really need to export these options, or are you just using them within the shell?

Answer (score 6):

Single quotes appear in the diagnostic line printed because of `set -x`. They do not get to `mvn`. The variable content (`-Dskip1 -Dskip2`) gets to `mvn` as a single argument because in `zsh` you don't need to quote variables rigidly (you do in POSIX-compliant shells).

The problem seems to be in the way `zsh` expands variables. I think you want word splitting to occur when `$SKIP` is unquoted ([like it happens in other shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)) but in `zsh` it does not normally occur.

Use `${=SKIP}` to [trigger word splitting after substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19530/108618).

Example:

```
% SKIP='-Dskip1 -Dskip2' 
% printf "%s\n" $SKIP   
-Dskip1 -Dskip2
% printf "%s\n" ${=SKIP}
-Dskip1
-Dskip2
%
```

Comment: +1 for the mention of the `${=parameter}` expansion and the extra info.